# AWS CDK. CodeCommit repository as source in CodeBuild

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit, aws-pipeline

I am trying to set a CodeCommit repository as a source for build project in AWS CDK.

So i am trying to do the following:

```
const codeCommitRepository = codecommit.Repository.fromRepositoryArn(this, "xxx", "arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:xxxaccount:xxxService");
const source = Source.codeCommit({repository: codeCommitRepository})
```

I am getting an error:
`TS2739: Type 'IRepository' is missing the following properties from type 'IRepository': notifiyOnPullRequestMerged, node`

Apperently this is not the way to do it, but I can't find the proper way. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: What's your CDK version?

Comment: At the end I realised my imports were messed up (and rpobably also versions of aws dependencies -> "aws-cdk-lib" and "aws-cdk").

Comment: You might want to either add the solution as an accepted answer or close the question.